# Searching for Failed attemps in /var/log/secure

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm currently writing a script to examine /var/log/secure file and report how many failed attempts there were that day. I need to output it in the following format:

```
Date: 03/15/10 Time: 10:30 Number of failed attempts: 8
```

Heres my code so far (Haven't done much)... Am I on the right track?

```
#!/bin/bash

classGID=5000
passfile=/var/log/secure


for i in $(grep ${classGID} ${passfile} | cut -d: -f1)
do

date=$(grep $i{passfile} | cut -d: -f2)

echo "Date: ${date}"

done
```

Comment: I recommend just using [logwatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/logwatch/).

Comment: or use perl to make things much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

c=1
while read line
do
        a=( $line )
        d="${a[@]::3}"
        logdate=$( date '+%F' -d"$d" )
        if [[ $logdate == $old_logdate ]]; then
                (( c++ ))
        elif [[ $old_logdate != $logdate ]]; then
                printf "%s\t%s\t%s%s\n" "Date: $old_logdate Number of failed attempts: $c"
                old_logdate=$logdate
                c=1
                continue
        else
                printf "%s\t%s\t%s%s\n" "Date: $logdate Number of failed attempts: $c"

        fi

done < <(grep 'authentication failure' /var/log/secure)
```

it's skip last record , I don't know why